# Jazz and IBM Products, Scope of Jazz? Which are the free components and what do they do?

Tags: sdk, scope, open-source, jazz

I've been reading a lot about integration between ALMs, and I was interested on IBM's so called open source platform, Jazz.

This could open the possibility to buy IBM products which integrate with the Jazz platform but for now I just want to understand the scope of the free product.

Can you actually grab the Jazz product and integrate with whatever with their SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. RTC is free for less than 10 developers: https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.6